# Download dataset using Bash

Tags: linux, bash, csv, ubuntu, dataset

I have a URL from which I have to download datasets

http://www.sec.gov/dera/data/Public-EDGAR-log-file-data/2016/Qtr4/log20161231.zip

I want Bash script, which will automatically takes the datasets.
I try but its not working.

Please Help me.

```
URL = "http://www.sec.gov/dera/data/Public-EDGAR-log-file-data/2016  
/Qtr4/log20161231.zip"
a=1
while [ "$a" -le 1 ]     loop1
do 
  wget -U firefox http://www.sec.gov/dera/data/Public-EDGAR-log-file-
  data/2016/Qtr4/log{20160723..20160725}.zip 

done
```

Comment: The syntax errors you get should give you good hints. For example, remove the spaces around the `=` in `URL = "http://..."` like so: `URL="http://..."`

Comment: while [ "$a" -le 1 ]     loop1
do  is this correct ?

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: You incorrectly set a URL variable, which is not used.  Then take out that "loop1" comment.  The while will only run once since you force a=1.  So... What do you want?  You want to loop on the dates for the filename log<DATE>.zip?